# Is it possible to make a JAR run configuration in VSCode, if so how?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, configuration

I've been trying to create a run/debug configuration for a JAR file with vscode, as one of my projects requires this. I can't seem to find a way to do it, so I thought I might ask here. Anyone know if this is possible, and if so how?

Comment: official docs?:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: I can’t find anything related to jar files there. Can you point me in the right direction? :-)

Comment: The .class file in .jar file? It seems like VSCode has no ability to debug .class file, maybe you can take a try in Intellij IDEA.